# Read lines from named pipe in Winapi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pipe, named-pipes

I am creating a named pipe connection between a .NET C# server app and a Win32 client app. In .NET C# it is possible to create a `System.IO.StreamReader` object from named pipe server/client stream. Is anything similar available in Winapi to read from named pipe line by line??

Comment: `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE` might help you.

Comment: There is no win32 function for reading file line by line.So you need to do some extra operations to process it into several lines.Refer to [Read text file (Unicode) in 'C' using native Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614483/read-text-file-unicode-in-c-using-native-win32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named pipes are special files, as such you read from them using the file IO API, namely [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile), etc.

The MSDN has a [complete example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client) for opening and reading from a named pipe.

Comment: The issue with `ReadFile` is that it requires to specify size of buffer which isn't constant in my use hence I am looking for another solution.

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt That’s simply how low level file IO (which is what the WinAPI provides) works. It *always* works like this. If you wan that, you’ll have to manage a dynamic buffer yourself, by reading fixed-sized chunks, determining the correct length and appending to a dynamically growing buffer.